# different values of max_connections

Tags: postgresql

The value of `max_connections` from `postgresql.conf` file is `100`

when I check the value from the query:

```
select *
from pg_gettings
```

I see `500`

I tried to reload the settings by:

```
select pg_reload_conf()
```

and checked again with

```
select *
from pg_gettings
```

but it still show `500`.

why the config file contains one value and the query return other value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the column `sourcefile` in that view to find out where the current value of that property comes from.

Maybe your configuration file uses an `include` to another config file or the value was changed using `alter system`. In that case `postgresql.auto.conf` would be listed as the `sourcefile`.